# Norm notation for amenable groups

Tags: functional-analysis, group-theory, normed-spaces

Let $G$ be a discrete group.
[integrated form of a representation]
We define $U_f\in Endomorphisms(l^1(G))$, and $U_f$ naturally as follows: let $\xi\in l^1(G)$, and
\begin{equation*}
    U_f(\xi)=\sum_{g\in G}f(g)U_x(\xi)
\end{equation*}
i.e. $U_f=\sum_{x\in G}f(x)U_x$, where $U_x\in Endomorphisms(V)$ by
\begin{equation*}
    x\xrightarrow{U}U_x
\end{equation*}
where $U$ is the map $: G\to End(l^1(G))$.

[Reduced $C^*$-algebra]
The operator norm closure of $\{U_f: f\in l^1(G)\}\in \mathcal{B}(l^1(G))$ is called the reduced $C^*$-algebra of $G$, denoted as $C_r^*(G)$.

We see that $C_r^*(F_2)$ is simple, and has no proper ideals, note $F_2$ can be thought of the group generated by $a,b, a^{-1}, b^{-1}$ with unit. Note that the trivial representation is not continuous for $\| \|_{C_r^*}$.

My question is about this norm notation, $\| \|_{C_r^*}$. What does it mean to not be continuous in this norm?

Comment: The reduced $C^*$-algebra is the norm closure in $B(\ell^2(G)).$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc so when we are talking about representation being not continuous in $ ||\cdot||_{C^*_r}$, do we mean as $||f_n - f||$ goes to zero in $l^1$ norm, $||U_{f_n} - U_f||$ does not go to zero in operator norm? Why do we index operator norm with ${C^*_r}$ then?